# What's the difference between the "rename" function and the "label" function in ´SAS´ and what are the use cases of each?

Tags: sas

SAS has both a `rename` function and a `label` function. Both of which appear to change the names of the data columns you are working with. Could anyone explain to me why there are two functions in SAS that appear to do the exact same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS data sets are monolith rectangles of data.  In a data base they are most often called rows and columns.  In SAS data parlance, the same are observations and variables.  The terms can be interchanged freely when communicating with a sufficiently knowledgeable audience.

A SAS variable has many metadata items that can be modified

- name, modify with `RENAME`
- label, modify with `LABEL`
- format, how the variables value is processed to construct a value representation as text
- informat, how input text is processed to construct the variables value
- length, media storage space to allocate for variable value (nominally the number of bytes)

When you use a data set viewer, it will display a top row of column headers.  The headers will be either the NAME or the LABEL :

- A NAME must conform to the SAS session naming rules set per the session option VALIDVARNAME.  The V7 rules set is that a name is 32 characters or less in length, and contains only _A-Z0-9 characters.

  - There are constructs known as *name literals* for more complicated situations.
- A LABEL is a character value of up to 200 characters.

There is a `RENAME=` data set option for changing the name of a variable during i/o
There is a `RENAME` statement for changing the name of a variable during DATA or PROC step processing

The is a `LABEL` statement for changing the label of a variable.

`Proc DATASETS` can be used to change variable metadata without rewriting a data set.  This can be very useful when changing variable metadata of a data set with many rows and/or many columns.

There are a several ways to examine variable metadata:

- The `VAR` window
- `Proc CONTENTS`
- SQL `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS`
- View `SASHELP.VCOLUMN`

All this information is readily available online in the [SAS Documentation](http://documentation.sas.com) web site.

Answer (score 1):

The LABEL of a variable is just a place to store a more user friendly description of the variable. The label is used in place of the name as column headers in some visualization tools, but it is not the same thing as the name.

Example:

```
 data want;
   set have;
   if visit=0 then baseline=value ;
   retain baseline;
   label baseline='Value at VIST 0';
 run;
```

The LABEL statement sets the LABEL attached to the variable.  The RENAME statement changes the NAME of the variable.

You can use a LABEL statement in most procedures.  You can normally only use the RENAME statement in a DATA step.